# Absolute Value Problem Using Only Variables

Tags: problem-solving, absolute-value

I recently encountered this problem, and it does not make sense to me. It looks like

Given $|a(b-cx)|=d$ , find the value of $|x-\frac{b}{c}|$

This was on a multiple choice test awhile ago, and I don't exactly remember the answer choices, but all of them were in simple fraction form, no addition or subtraction. Example $\frac{ac}{db}$. That is, of course, probably not the right answer, just an example of how the answer choices looked. Anyway, this problem bothered me so much that I decided to post it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't delete the question. But, a couple of people were able to answer it no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a,b,c,d>0$,

$$|a(b-cx)|=d\implies \left|x-\frac bc\right|=\frac d{ac}.$$

Answer (score 0):

It holds for $a \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$:
$$|a(b-cx)| = d,$$
$$|a| |b-cx| = d,$$
$$|b-cx|=\frac{d}{|a|},$$
$$\left| c \right| \left| x - \frac{b}{c} \right| = \frac{d}{|a|}, $$
$$\left| x - \frac{b}{c} \right| = \frac{d}{|a c|}.$$

Comment: No, I'm sorry they were totally right. I made a typo. I assume that they realized it was supposed to be c, not a, or you could not have gotten an answer.